# Detecting broken defective biscuits in a binary image

Tags: image-processing, opencv, image-recognition

I am new to OpenCV and I'm trying to count and locate broken or cracked biscuits
(those which *are not perfect circles* as they should be) in the image.

What kind of strategy should I follow?

Any suggestion can help to open my mind. Regards.

Comment: Can you may provide sample images? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Upload sample images in imageshack.us and provide its link in your question. Then you may get better answers.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very abstract (it would be better if you provide some picture), but I can try to answer it.

First of all you have to detect *all busquits* on your image. To do this you have to find *bisquit color* (maybe [HSV color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) would be better for your aim) on your picture and convert input image to single channel image (or matrix), each element of this matrix can be:

- **1 (or 255)** if this pixel belongs to bisquit
- **0** if not.

*[OpenCV function [inRange](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/operations_on_arrays.html#cv-inrange) may help you to do such conversion.]*

When bisquits are detected you can:

1. Use [HoughCircles](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_feature_detection.html#cv-houghcircles) to detect *normal bisquits* (if *normal bisquit* is round).
2. Find contours of each bisquit (take a look at [findContours](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours)) and compare each contour with normal bisquit (if it's not round) using [cross-corellation](http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/correlate/) or maybe other methods ([Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) etc).

Also look at [HoughCircle tutorial](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html) to detect just circles if your image doesn't contain other circles (except bisquits).